# Venn diagram related question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

An analysis of the survey of $320$ school pupils highlighted the following facts:

•   $50$ pupils live in New Town, travel to school by bus and have canteen lunch.

•   $110$ pupils live in New Town and have canteen lunch

•   $160$ pupils live in New Town

•   $90$ pupils travel by bus and have canteen lunch

•   $130$ pupils travel by bus

•   $30$ pupils live in New Town, travel to school by bus but do not have canteen lunch

•   $90$ pupils do not live in New Town, do not travel to school by bus and do not have canteen lunch

Depict the above information in the form of a Venn diagram.
The Principal wishes to know how many pupils have lunch at the school canteen.  Please help him find that out, and also help us understand how you arrived at the answer.

Comment: What is your question about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the pupils has three boolean properties N (lives on New Town or not), B (travels by bus or not) and C (has canteen lunch or not). There are 2^3 = 8 possible cases which can be depicted as follows:

[image]

The yellow figures were directly given in the question. The red figures can be derived. Example: 90 pupils travel by bus and have canteen lunch. Therefore, $|B C| = |N B C| + |N' B C|$ must be 90. We know from "50 pupils live in New Town, travel to school by bus and have canteen lunch" that $|N B C|$ is 50 and conclude $|N' B C|$ to be 40.

The canteen pupils sum up to $50+60+40+20 = 170$

As a [Venn Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), this would look as follows:

[image]